# What does '=>' imply in typescript/javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have saw tons of '=>' in some code I found online. Can anyone explain to me like I'm 5?

(I am looking for code, and I will post it here once I find it)..

Got it:

```
            var directive = () =>
        {
            return new MyDirective();
        };
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions Google is your friend here.

Comment: TypeScript arrow functions : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()=>` is simply a `lambda` function, which (in this case) means nothing more than a shorthand notation for a `function` without a name taking 0 paramaters.

You could have written `var directive=function(){return new MyDirective();};`

Take a look at [John Papas](http://www.johnpapa.net/typescriptpost2/) blog Post.

Answer (score 3):

this is ECMASCRIPT 6 standard arrow function.

In this case `directive` is assigned a function with 0 arguments and one return statement

Details are documented [here in MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks! That clarified everything ;)

Comment: The context is `TypeScript` ;) But nevertheless it is correct.

Comment: TypeScript is for js and very similar